# Create post excerpts in PHP

Tags: php

A develper wrote the following PHP code to create the post excerpt, as below:

```
/* This function allows for the auto-creation of post excerpts
======================================================================== */
function truncate_post_simple($amount,$quote_after=false) {
  $truncate = get_the_content();
  $truncate = strip_shortcodes( $truncate );
  $truncate = strip_tags($truncate);
  $truncate = substr($truncate, 0, strrpos(substr($truncate, 0, $amount), ' '));
  echo $truncate;
  echo "...";
  if ($quote_after) echo('');
}
```

I cannot understand the following line:

```
$truncate = substr($truncate, 0, strrpos(substr($truncate, 0, $amount), ' '));
```

It seems that the extraction is the first part of the post with $amount of characters, and then it will remove an extra part that beginning with a space.

I cannot understand why he will do this. Why don't use

```
$truncate = substr($truncate, 0, $amount);
```

directly, or if he wants to remove extra spaces, using:

```
$truncate = $rtrim(substr($truncate, 0, $amount));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they were trying to find the last space before the `$amount`-th character to be truncated. This way, a word is not clipped in the middle. You can break it down as follows:

```php
// finds the last space in $truncate before the $amount-th character
$lastSpace = strrpos(substr($truncate, 0, $amount), ' ');
// truncate the string to the last space
$truncate = substr($truncate, 0, $lastSpace);
```

Some examples may help:

```php
$truncate = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$amount = 12;
$lastSpace = strrpos(substr($truncate, 0, $amount), ' '); // 9
$result = substr($truncate, 0, $lastSpace); // "The quick"
```

If we had just used `$amount` directly, the word "brown" would have been
clipped in the middle

```php
$result = substr($truncate, 0, $amount); // "The quick br";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand why the developer will do so.

Answer (score 2):

Spread it out and annotate it.

```php
$truncate = substr( // substring from 0 until the first space before $amount
  $truncate,
  0,
  strrpos( // position of the first space, counted from the end of the substring.
    substr( // blind substring of length $amount, starting from 0
      $truncate,
      0,
      $amount
    ),
    ' '
  )
);
```